# Mockito's @InjectMock annotation

Tags: bdd, mockito

I'm a little confused with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and `@InjectMock` annotations and how they are related to each other. As per my understanding by giving `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` we don't need to initialize the mock like `mock(ABC.class)`.

On the other hand `@InjectMocks` injects the mock automatically with getters and setters. The documentation says:

> `@InjectMocks` currently it only supports setter injection.  If you prefer constructor injection - please contribute a patch....

What I don't understand is that when I remove `@InjectMocks` below I get nullpointer exception for the tests as dependency is null. Does that mean construtor based inject is supported? Or does it has something to do with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Here's the code

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    @Mock
    private Dependency dependency;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass cls = new MyClass(dependency);
    //...
}

class MyClass {
    private Dependency dependency;

    MyClass(Dependency dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the latest release, [Mockito supports constructor injection](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.0-rc1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#23).

See the latest [javadoc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.0-rc1/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html).